# Using a theme in pidgin in windows

Tags: windows, pidgin

I am trying to apply a theme to Pidgin in Windows 7 but cannot find out how.
I looked [here](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoIchangethelookandfeel) which tells me to place them in:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\GTK\2.0\share\themes
```

but that didn't work, so I tried:

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Roaming\.purple\GTK\2.0\share\themes
```

To no avail. Where do I put them or is there a plugin to do this? The option appears to be available in preferences but iI don't know where to put them so it can detect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried restarting the app after putting the themes in the folder? Sometimes, applications only scan certain plugins or themes folders when they are started.

Comment: tried this to no avail

Comment: Awfully strange behavior, in this case...

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If I choose any theme other than MS-Windows, I get a generic bland gray theme.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the last update. Got me in the right direction.

However for Pidgin Portable, one needs to follow http://portableapps.com/node/23728 Look at the more detailed instructions in the message thread below the main explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you use are speaking about the GTK theme, which only affects the buttons/menus/other controls. (And the GTK theme is set in `~/.gtkrc-2.0` in case you want to change that too.)

Smiley themes should be installed to `~/.purple/smileys/` (`%AppData%\.purple\smileys\`)

Comment: I am using Windows. This does does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesse alludes to, your `gtkrc` is found in `C:\Program Files\pidgin\gtk\etc\gtk-2.0` according to the [What is a gtkrc file and where can I find it?](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#WhatisagtkrcfileandwherecanIfindit) FAQ entry.

See also: [How do I change to look and feel?](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoIchangethelookandfeel)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is years old, but I stubmled across it recently.  Here is a newer tutorial that uses Windows 7 and Pidgin 2.7.9 (which does not come with the GTK stuff installed)

http://www.techjawa.com/2010/11/02/guide-theme-pidgin-in-windows-updated/